# Google Cloud Speech API using php

Tags: php, json, speech-recognition, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to call Google Cloud Speech API by using PHP and got a problem.

```
$stturl = "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize?key=xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$upload = file_get_contents("1.wav");
$upload = base64_encode($upload);

$data = array(
    "config"    =>  array(
        "encoding"      =>  "LINEAR16",
        "sampleRate"    =>  16000,
        "languageCode"  =>  "en-US"
    ),
    "audio"     =>  array(
        "Content"       =>  $upload,
    )
);

$jsonData = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $stturl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The result says that it is INVALID JSON PAYLOAD.

> { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received.
>   Unknown name \"content\" at 'audio': Cannot find field.", "status":
>   "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [ { "@type":
>   "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest", "fieldViolations": [ {
>   "field": "audio", "description": "Invalid JSON payload received.
>   Unknown name \"content\" at 'audio': Cannot find field." } ] } ] } } "

I think this is because $upload isn't configured correctly.
According Google Cloud Speech API, it should be "A base64-encoded string".
https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionAudio

That's why I used **base64_encode** function, but it seems JSON doesn't process this value correctly.
Any thoughts?

Comment: You should `base64_encode($upload)` and also change `Content` to `content`. Should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct the properly formatted input as an array and then json encode it. For example, to send a file, base64encode it as "content" and submit to the API as shown:

```
$data = array(
    "config" => array(
        "encoding" => "LINEAR16",
        "sample_rate" => $bitRate,
        "language_code" => "en-IN"
    ),
   "audio" => array(
        "content" => base64_encode($filedata)
    )
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                              

$ch = curl_init($googlespeechURL);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
   'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
   'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result_array = json_decode($result, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

please make 'content' instead of 'Content'

small letter 'c'

its work for me.